# How performance for prediction with tensorflow session.run() and prediction with tf-serving differs?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

System configuration: 32core, 128GB RAM

I have successfully deployed model with tensorflow-serving and model inference is done with gRPC request. It might be calling session.run() internally while prediction. With this approach, it takes 3sec for batch of 100 document.

In case of direct deployment of tensorflow model (not with tf-serving), we pass batch of documents to session.run(model.prediction, feed_dict={}) and do inference.

Question is, in which way tensorflow-serving differs from direct deployment in case of performance and optimization? What type of optimization is done in tf-serving while inference?

Thank you.